# Speed up the search of substring inside big string

Tags: python

I have written the following python snippet of code which actually finds if a specific substring exists inside a string. Due to the fact that the loop is running around 1000 times, it takes around 5-7 sec to complete.

```
for style in all_available_gs_styles:
     if style.sld_title is not None:
       if str(style.sld_title) not in ('line', 'point', 'polygon', 'Polygon', 'Default Line', 'Default Point'):
         if 'PolygonSymbolizer' in style.sld_body and layer_geom == 'polygon':
            gs_styles.append((style.name, style.sld_title))
         elif 'LineSymbolizer' in style.sld_body and layer_geom == 'line':
            gs_styles.append((style.name, style.sld_title))
         elif 'PointSymbolizer' in style.sld_body and layer_geom == 'point':
            gs_styles.append((style.name, style.sld_title))
```

I was wondering if there is a more efficient way to search for a string inside a text which is around 50 lines long. What would be a quicker approach?

***EDIT***
Following the accepted answer, the time of execution was reduced to 4-5 seconds. Still not sufficient but better than before.

Comment: You should fix your indentation. This code will not run.

Comment: This code is running ok. The indentation is messed up when I add the code snippet in stackoverflow cause the code snippet tool doesn't maintain spaces. Moreover your comment is not costructive.

Comment: It *might* be faster to swap the order of the tests - the string comparison (e.g. `layer_geom == 'polygon`) could be faster than the `in` test, especially depending on the size of `style.sld_body`. Having it fail sooner could speed things up.  Since those 3 inner `if` statements all do the same action, it might be faster if you can have a single test for a `false` state and do nothing in those cases.

Probably won't affect speed, but you should also replace `if style.sld_title is not None:` with `if style.sld_title:`

Comment: The inner `if` does not really make sense. No matter what, the same command is executed so you can merge the conditions

Comment: You should probably have the `layer_gem==` conditions **before** the `if ___ in style.sld_body` conditions instead of after, because the equality will be faster to check.

Comment: @user1919 Take a look at my last edit. Maybe this helps a bit more..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would go with something more compact but still fairly readable like this:

```
geoms   = ('line', 'point', 'polygon')  # see EDIT
invalid = {'line', 'point', 'polygon', 'Polygon', 'Default Line', 'Default Point'}
for style in all_available_gs_styles:
    if style.sld_title and str(style.sld_title) not in invalid:
        if any(layer_geom == x and '{}Symbolizer'.format(x.capitalize()) in style.sld_body for x in geoms):
            gs_styles.append((style.name, style.sld_title))
```

Note that the gains are only conditional:

E.g., checking for equality check first because it is faster is the right way to go **but** it will only help in cases it returns `False`.

The bottleneck in your code (and mine) are these **`in`** checks (`if 'PolygonSymbolizer' in style.sld_body` ) but without knowing the data you are working with I cannot help any further.

---

**EDIT**

Using [Euler's formula for polyhedra](https://plus.maths.org/content/eulers-polyhedron-formula) we can assume that for every polygon, the number of lines (E) is going to be greater than the number of vertices (V) and as such, the most frequent entity in `style.sld_body`. We can take advantage of that to make the `any` short-circuit **more-often** by re-arranging the `geom` tuple like `geoms   = ('line', 'point', 'polygon')`. This will of course not have a significant impact but it is the best we can do.

Comment: You might also get a bit of a speedup by turning the tuple in the outer if check into  a set (created once before the loop) (and `geoms` are also the same in each iteration)

Comment: I think the `set` only makes sense if you create it _outside_ of the loop, otherwise you still have O(n) (well, O(6)) for _creating_ the set in each iteration.

Answer (score 1):

Parse the body into a `set` so you can search it more efficiently.

```
for style in all_available_gs_styles:
     if style.sld_title is not None:
       if str(style.sld_title) not in ('line', 'point', 'polygon', 'Polygon', 'Default Line', 'Default Point'):
         body_words = set(style.sld_body.split(' '))
         if 'PolygonSymbolizer' in body_words and layer_geom == 'polygon':
            gs_styles.append((style.name, style.sld_title))
         elif 'LineSymbolizer' in body_words and layer_geom == 'line':
            gs_styles.append((style.name, style.sld_title))
         elif 'PointSymbolizer' in body_words and layer_geom == 'point':
            gs_styles.append((style.name, style.sld_title))
```